# vba colour of the cell

Tags: excel, vba

i need help for vba
how to colour the cell(1,1) in red colour

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, this is a programmer forum

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Test()

        'In "with statement" we include the name of workbook & the name of worksheet we want to execute the code.
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            'Using cell referencing
            .Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed

            'Using range referencing
            .Range("A1").Interior.Color = vbRed

        End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cells(1,1).interior.colorindex = 3
```

Comment: cells(1,1).interior.color=rgb(255,0,0)

Comment: Cells(1,1).interior.color = vbRed